# How can I get rid of these dents in my mesh?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I tried sculpting over these dents then smoothening them out but it didn't work it would just appear again, how can I get rid of them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your mesh is way too dense, I am not sure what are you going to use it for or if you need it that dense but I would recommend one of two things... go to sculpt and smooth it with a weak Smooth brush (strength like 0.05-0.1) or remesh it manually/automatically to lower density and repair it and the subdiv it again.

Comment: Do they deform surface or you don't like topology?

Comment: @vklidu it deforms the surface, using the smooth brush and makes the dents sink down instead of actually smoothing it  :^/

Comment: there are probably already twisted faces in center ... us suggested - Remeshing Modifier with some lower density could solve more of your issues arround the object at this stage of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try grid fill:

1. delete all vertices around the damage
2. connect all vertices around the hole
3. grid fill

[image]